# Run javascript after gif is fully loaded with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, gif, onload

I know I can use

```
$(".container").ready(function(){
  // Run after DOM loaded
});
```

to run code after the DOM has been fully loaded. This includes images though it seems it doesn't include GIF-images. From what I can see, loading the first frame of the gif counts as "loaded".

Is there a way to trigger code after the fill gif has been loaded?

Comment: As I said, I know the "ready" function. It doesn't seem to include gifs

Answer (score 2):

The `<img>` element has on `onload` event - this should do the trick.

If you'd like to use jQuery for that, you can read about it here: https://api.jquery.com/load-event/

Answer (score 2):

Images have a [`onload event`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Tech/XUL/Attribute/image.onload) that fires.

```
$(".image-selector").on("load", function(){
   // Run after the image has loaded.
});
```

If you are targetting an older version of IE (pre IE9) there are sometimes troubles if dynamically changing the `src` property and you'll also have to check the `image.complete` property.

Edit: Went looking for the property name and found this question: [jQuery callback on image load (even when the image is cached)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3877027/jquery-callback-on-image-load-even-when-the-image-is-cached)

Answer (score 0):

You may use the [imagesloaded](http://imagesloaded.desandro.com/) plugin for this use case.

Answer (score -1):

How about this

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("gif selector").load(function(){
        alert("gift loaded.");
    });
});
```

Example: http://www.w3schools.com/jquery/tryit.asp?filename=tryjquery_event_load